# Jagged Lines when plotting the Confidence Interval for Regression Model

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, confidence-interval

I am trying to create a Multiple Linear Regression model for an assignment that predicts the Selling Price of houses. After a considerable amount of work, I created this model that compares the actual sale price to the predicted sale price:

[image]

As you can clearly see, the blue matlines (confidence interval) are very jagged. Even the prediction interval lines are somewhat jagged. This is the code I had used to create it;

```
model_final <- lm((SalePrice) ~ log10(Lot.Area) + (Total.Bsmt.SF) + (Gr.Liv.Area) + (Wood.Deck.SF) + Screen.Porch  + (Open.Porch.SF) + (Year.Built) + (Year.Remod.Add) + factor(Bsmt.Full.Bath) + factor(Bedroom.AbvGr) + factor(Fireplaces) + (Garage.Cars), data = train)


pred_final <- predict(model_final, newdata = test)
model_final_confint <- predict(model_final, test, interval = "c")
model_final_predint <- predict(model_final, test, interval = "p")
model_final_rmsep <- RMSEP(actual_saleprice, pred_final)

par(pty = "s")

plot(pred_final, actual_saleprice, xlab = "Predicted Sale Price", ylab = "Actual Sale Price", main = "Final Model For Sale Price Projections", xlim = range, ylim = range)
matlines(sort(pred_final), model_final_confint[order(pred_final), 2:3], lty = 1, lwd = 1, col = "blue")
matlines(sort(pred_final), model_final_predint[order(pred_final), 2:3], lty = 1, lwd = 1, col = "red")
abline(0,1)`
```

I have a feeling it could also be due to the data; I created the training/test sets using an updated data frame that excludes observations with a cook's distance greater than 4/n-k-1

Any advice would be much appreciated, as I am still very new to this!

Comment: Please consult the formula for the standard error of response: you will see that it does not depend solely on the predicted response.